# Store array of objects in DB column. Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

Trying to store array of objects in DB and getting an error : array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array

```
$tmp = new Projects;
$tmp->items = '{"id":"108124505876479","name":"Wakeboarding"},{"id":"112003352149145","name":"Bouldering"},{"id":"110008522357035","name":"Handball"}';
$tmp->save();
```

Found a lot of answers, but no one is useful.

Update (model file and migration added):

Model file:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Projects extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'items' => 'array',
    ];

}
```

Migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProjectsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('gID', 100);
            $table->string('name', 100);
            $table->text('items');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('projects');
    }
}
```

and the function:

```
$tmp = new Projects;
$tmp->name = "aaa";
$tmp->gID = "FLSKJDF3R23R";
$tmp->items = [["id" => "108124505876479", "name" => "Wakeboarding"],["id" =>  "aa", "name" => "volkswagen" ]];
$tmp->save();
```

Comment: where is `array_merge()` used ?

Comment: I see missing `[` and `]` brackets to wrap your array

Comment: (1/1) ErrorException
array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array
in HasAttributes.php (line 769)
at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ezra-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php', 769, array('defaults' => array('created_at', 'updated_at')))

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your `Projects` class is an Eloquent Model. With the code given, it is not clear how `items` is mapped to MySQL and whether you told your model that you want to use `items` as an array.

In your migration, you can set it to be a text or json field. E.g.

```
$table->text('items');
```

Then in your model, you can declare it as an array:

```
protected $casts = [
    'items' => 'array',
];
```

Now Laravel's Eloquent Model takes care of mapping your array to a string when it gets stored to the DB and vice versa.

As you get an array_merge error, I assume you actually set it up this way and Eloquent causes this error, as you pass in a string.

So you probably can just call:

```
$tmp->items = [["id" => "108124505876479", "name" => "Wakeboarding"],["id" => ... ... ]];
```

See Eloquent's casting capabilities:
[Array and Json casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators)

Comment: copied your example and: "Array to string conversion"

Comment: @aleXela: what do you mean with "Array to string conversion"?

Comment: It would help if you could add your Migration and Model code to your question.

Comment: added, both model and migration

Comment: You may want to set the table name `protected $table = 'projects'`, as your class name is plural. From the documentation: _By convention, the "snake case", plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified._ .Not sure how this works when the class name is already plural.

Comment: The other thing I see in your original error message: HasAttributes line 769 is where Laravel merges the dates fields and complaints that your $dates is not an array. However, you just use default timestamps. So that doesn' make sense as you don't set it. What version of Laravel are you on?

Comment: using laravel 5.4.32